# Input same value in few sequential array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

so I found this:

```
std::fill_n(array, 100, value);
```

but I suspect it might not be what I'm looking for. I have an appay *pointer and need to put same value in few sequential elements fast, because they are pixels, and there's lots of them.

So I use:

```
*(pointer)=*(pointer+1)=value;
```

sometimes  there's
*(pointer)=*(pointer+1)=*(pointer+2)=value;
but the first case is most crucial. One additional "+" is not a problem, I know, but when I use SDL's function to fill screen black (or other), it works kind of fast, and I don't know how it is optimized.

So if I need to costumly input same value in few neighbour elements of array, is there some cool trick.

Maybe some cast to (Uint64) and <<32 to place 2 same values in 2 integers trick?

Okey, sorry I didn't explained what this is for from the start.
So I render voxel object and sometimes after rotation there is spots on screen inside the object, where no pixel is drown, because I drow only kind of outer layer of object. And I want to do smoothing by basically stretching object by one pixel to the right. So while im putting pixel, I need to put one just like him to his right.

Comment: I usually don't like to recommend it (it works completely outside the type system), but in this case [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) may be a real option. It is likely to be highly optimised for your platform. **Edit** How many elements at a time, and how often?

Comment: @BoBTFish: memset is only useful for repeating a single byte-sized value. It sounds like he wants to fill 32-bit values.

Comment: How about looking into said SDL functions (http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/03bca9a4180d/src/video/SDL_fillrect.c )? Short answer: no, you can't beat hand-tuned asm/intrinsics/unrolled loops with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill 100 (or even 1000) `unsigned int` elements, then you can choose any method you want, be it `std::fill_n`, or `for` loop - the number is so small you won't see the difference, even if you do this operation very often.

However, if you want to set values for a bigger array, say, 8k x 8k texture with pixels composed of 4 unsigned color components, then there is a short comparison of the methods you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdint>

int main(){
    long unsigned const size = 8192 * 8192 * 4;
    unsigned* arr = new unsigned[size];

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    memset(arr, 0, size*sizeof(unsigned));

    clock_t t2 = clock();
    std::fill_n(arr, size, 123);

    clock_t t3 = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        *(arr + i) = 123;

    clock_t t4 = clock();
    int64_t val = 123;
    val = val << 32 | 132;
    for(int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i)
        *(int64_t*)(arr + i * 2) = val;

    clock_t t5 = clock();

    std::cout << "memset = " << t2 - t1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std::fill_n = " << t3 - t2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "for 32 = " << t4 - t3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "for 64 = " << t5 - t4 << std::endl;

    delete arr;

    return 0;
}
```

**1. `memset`**

This function is used here only to show you how fast *zeroing* your array could be, in comparison to other methods. It's the fastest solution, but only usable when you want to set every byte to the same value (especially useful with `0` and `0xFF` in your case, I guess).

**2. `std::fill_n` and `for` loop with 32-bit value**

`std::fill_n` looks to be the slowest of the solutions, and it is even slightly **slower** than the `for` solution with 32-bit values.

**3. `for` loop with 64-bit value ON 64-bit SYSTEM**

I guess this is the solution you could go for, since it wins this competition. However, if your machine were 32-bit, then I would expect the results to be comparable to the loop with 32-bit values (depends on the compiler and processor), since processor will handle one 64-bit value as two 32-bit values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one 64-bit variable to put a value into two (or more) 32-bit (or smaller) consecutive elements. There are many ifs.  Obviously you should be on 64 bit patform, and you should know how your platform handle alignment.

Somethin like this:

```
uint32_t  val = ...;
uint64_t  val2 = val;
(val2  <<= 32) |= val;

for (uint32_t* p = ...; ...)
     *(uint64_t*) p = val2;
```

You can use similar techniques with greater effect, if you use SSE.

Comment: 32-bit systems also have 64-bit integers. Also, val is 32-bit you are trying to shift every bit away; you need to cast it to uint64_t BEFORE you start shifting.

Comment: Usually on 32-bit system, 64-bit values are implemented as 32-value in CPU microcode. For example, you need 2 cycles, to transfer 64-bit value on 32-bit system.  I might be still faster though.  Missing cast to 64-bit - fixed.